# Tkz-euclide and 'altitude' option

Tags: tkz-euclide

I am using Lyx on a Windows machine.

I have extracted the following code from the tkz-Euclide manual.
However, when I try to run it., the following error message appears.

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/altitude' and I am going
to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-90]
    \tkzDefPoint(0,1){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,4){C}
    \tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal normed,K=7](C,A)
    \tkzGetPoint{B}
    \tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](A,C)
    \tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](C,B)
    \tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](B,A)
    \tkzDrawLine[altitude,dashed,color=magenta](B,C,A)
    \tkzGetPoint{P}
    \tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above](C){$C$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[left](P){$P$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[auto](B,A){$c$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[auto,swap](B,C){$a$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[auto,swap](C,A){$b$}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly where in which manual version did you find that? I can't find `\tkzDrawLine[altitude ...` anywhere in https://texdoc.org/serve/tkz-euclide/0 It looks like the `altitude` option is meant to be used with `\tkzDefLine`, not `\tkzDrawLine`.

Comment: Pg 68. It seems that I am using an old version of the manual. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AnthonyMacks   Torbjørn T. gives the good answer. Now you need to use `\tkzDefLine`with the option `altitude`. I adopted this principle in order to separate the calculation part from the drawing part. I hope in a near future to use "lua" for the calculation part and then TikZ for the drawing.